# Oracle11g - Not able to create user

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to create new User from my SYSDBA account, but when I run the Query it is not responding even after long time. Same issue also occurs when I try to IMPDP.

here is my Query.

```
create user USER_NEW
    identified by USER_NEW
     default tablespace MY_TABLESPACE;
```

I am not getting any error in Alert Log file, also tablespace has 99% free space (100MB).

Comment: Are you able to connect as a normal, non-SYSDBA users? Are you connecting locally or over SQL\*Net? Are there any earlier messages in the alert log? I'd expect some error still, but I'm wondering abut something like archive log dest being full. Not sure if what you're seeing is diagnosable really though, without access to the machine and all the logs.

Comment: @AlexPoole, All I am talking about is Production Database, Every users can connect without any problem. My server is up and running. Logs are generated perfectly having more than required archive destination. It is pretty hard for me to understand what the issue is, Because alert log doesn't show anything noticeable in this scope. But still I am investigating alert log for any oversight.

Comment: Maybe look in `v$session_wait` and other performance view to look for locks. Presumably something is locking one of the internal tables. Are all your users actually connecting directly or going through a pre-existing connection pool in your application, maybe? Seems strange that impdp would block but SQL\*Plus wouldn't. (MOS doc 109774.1 looks slightly similar; but also sounds like bug 13814497 maybe)